# OnItemClick not responding to clicks

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

have searched [listview OnClick not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334893/android-horizontallistview-onitemclick-not-working) [working pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308192/android-programming-onitemclicklistener-for-multiple-listviews-doesnt-work),  doesn't solve.

my Activity populates listview by calling a custom adapter 
*MyArrayAddapter* 
 which extends *ArrayAdapter* class.

**The problem: onItemClick() or setOnItemClick() ain't responding.**

when i click on any of the items no action takes place, not even log statements get executed.

<<>>

code snippet:

Under my class which extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, **I initialize and call following functions in OnCreate() method:**

```
    private void listViewSet() {

        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(    this,   R.id.tvrow, rootListWrapper );
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(    adapter     );  
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(    this    );  //******
        listView.performClick();
    }
```

Even toast doesnt show up :(

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.v(  "OnCLick", "asdfhjdf" );
        Toast.makeText(  this,  "Component "+ rootListWrapper.get( position ).toString() + " clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        root = rootListWrapper.get(  position  );
        rootListWrapper = root.children;        
        this.listViewSet();
    }
```

Note: when i click on an item of the listview, i get exactly same messages only differing in timestamp. I get 7-8  such new messages. LogCat before click:

```
03-15 09:54:06.507: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 09:54:06.877: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 09:54:06.877: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 09:54:06.947: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 09:54:06.947: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 09:54:07.117: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 09:54:07.117: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 09:54:07.297: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

after click:

```
03-15 10:05:36.458: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 10:05:36.458: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 10:05:36.480: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 10:05:40.817: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 10:05:40.817: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 10:05:40.917: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-15 10:05:40.960: W/Trace(1825): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

The layout for the activity:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BigClass" >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout for row items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:padding="20dp"
      >     

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvrow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Component" />

    <LinearLayout android:weightSum="9"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@id/tvrow"   >

    <Button      android:id="@+id/bL"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_right"        
         />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bC
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:background="@drawable/component2"
         />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/bR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:background="@drawable/blue_right"
        /> 
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It populates perfectly for first time, but I want when I click i should be able to repopulate it by changing the parameters and calling the setAdapter() method again.

Solving this will surely help out many others, as i see many have unsolved doubts.

java file for class in question:

```
public class BigClass extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{




    List<Node> rootListWrapper;
    Node root;
    ListView listView;
    GetMethodEx getJSONString;
    JSONObject jObject;
    BigClass HealthNext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_health_display);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        rootListWrapper = new ArrayList<Node>();
        root = new Node();
        getJSONString = new GetMethodEx();
        jObject = new JSONObject();

        //values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        //        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        //        "Linux", "OS/2" };

        this.jsonDataFetch();
        this.listViewSet();

    }
        private void jsonDataFetch() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try{
             jObject=new JSONObject(    getJSONString.getInternetData() );           
             root = root.createNode(    jObject );  
             Log.v( "component",    jObject.getString("status") );
             rootListWrapper.add(   root    );
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("component", rootListWrapper.toString());
    }


        private void listViewSet() {
            // Define a new Adapter
            // First parameter - Context
            // Second parameter - Layout for the row
            // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
            // Fourth - the Array of data

            MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(    this,   R.id.tvrow, rootListWrapper );
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(    adapter     );  
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(    this    );
            listView.performClick();
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.v(  "OnCLick", "asdfhjdf" );
        Toast.makeText(  BigClass.this,  "Component "+ rootListWrapper.get( position ).toString() + " clicked.",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        root = rootListWrapper.get(  position  );
        rootListWrapper = root.children;
        HealthNext.jsonDataFetch();
        HealthNext.listViewSet();
    }

}
```

LOGCAT updated: after using focusable:false attribute on 3 buttons.

```
03-15 10:57:44.798: V/OnCLick(958): asdfhjdf
03-15 10:57:44.952: D/AndroidRuntime(958): Shutting down VM
03-15 10:57:44.952: W/dalvikvm(958): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at com.example.@@@@@@.BigClass.onItemClick(BigClass.java:86)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-15 10:57:44.992: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i dont want to implement performClick() at all.. I read on some forum that performClick() can be used to remove this prob. No intention of using a onClick() method. interested only in OnItemClick()

Comment: is it a listActivity???

Comment: no. its a simple "Activity". With ListView listView object taken  from  activity_layout.xml

and this listview is inflated with extended ArrayAdapter class object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Replace your row xml file with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
      >     

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvrow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Component" />

    <LinearLayout android:weightSum="9"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@id/tvrow"   >

    <Button  android:id="@+id/bL"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_right"        
         />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bC"
        android:layout_weight="1"
   android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:background="@drawable/component2"
         />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/bR"
      android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:background="@drawable/blue_right"
        /> 
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Your custom adapter may have a focusable items like (EditText, Button) etc, try to set focus of row items to false

Comment: where should i set these attributes to false?

1. one layout is which has <ListView> tag only
2. Second layout has all elements which form an item of the row.

Comment: posted activity_layout.xml   and row.xml towards the end.

Comment: @gizmoUb for your 3 buttons set android:focusable=false

Comment: still Not working!
where else should i add focusable attribute? did you have a look at row.xml?

Comment: @gizmoUb Add your Adapter code also I'll post the complete answer for you..In the mean while try setting  android:descendantFocusability="true" for your relative layout of row.xml

Comment: i will, the OnItemClick() method actually does execute now, as i can see Log.v message printing. Thanks!!
Hwever, soon it stops, with message from logcat as: (see post)

Comment: @gizmoUb post your logcat message in the above question

Comment: @gizmoUb it seems your  rootListWrapper.get(  position  ); returning null get the value like this parent.get(position)

Comment: If you got your answer, then mark this as answer by cliking the right mark beside the answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
 listView.performClick();
```

Would trigger onClick() on the listview and not on individual items in the list.

So, you should also have to implement the onClick() method to intercept clicks on your listview.

Comment: okay in that case i dont want to implement performClick() at all..
I read on some forum that performClick() can be used to remove this prob.
No intention of using a onClick() method. interested only in OnItemClick()

Comment: As Pragnani mentioned, do you have such a situation?